# How to show that a function space is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\text{Fun}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) = \{f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\mid \text{$f$ is a function}\}$ be the set of functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. This set is endowed with an addition determined by $$(f+g)\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}: x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)$$ and a scalar multiplication given by $$\cdot \colon \mathbb{R}\times \text{Fun}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\to \text{Fun}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$$ given by $(c\cdot f)(x)=cf(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

How can one prove that $\text{Fun}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is a (real) vector space?

Comment: You should read the definition of a vector space. That's a list of requirements. Check that each one of them applies. Then you're done.

Comment: The most common version of this list of requirements is given in [the table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)